# Why does slicing from higher negative index to smaller negative index gives empty string?

Tags: slice, python-3.7

can someone please explain to me why this gives empty string as its output and not 'oht';

> > > word='python'
> > >
> > > word[-2:-5]

Answer (score 0):

You will get your expected result  by running the below Code

```
>>word[-2:1:-1]
'oht'
```

Usually, The slicing happens from left to right. For Example,

```
word='python'
word[-2:]
```

Results

> 'on'

```
word[:-5]
```

Will Results

> 'p'

While Doing to attempt it together

```
word[-2:-5]
```

There will be no output to give you a result. The first index should be smaller than the second index. in your question -2 is greater than -5.

Comment: does that means it slices forward alone and not backwards?

Comment: Usually, that's the way. in order to get the expected result, you have to put some other index in it. I have updated it in the result.